# Entity Framework performing INSERT where it should not be

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following Entity Data models, simplified for brevity;

```
public abstract class Entity<T> : BaseEntity, IEntity<T>
{
    [Key]
    public virtual T Id { get; set; }
}

public class User : Entity<int>
{
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; } 
}

public class Category : Entity<int>
{
    public string Description { get; set; } 
}


public class List : Entity<int>
{
    public Category Category { get; set; } 
}
```

These are accessed from the DbContext using a DbContext exposed by either a generic service, or a more customised implementation to provide business logic.

When I publish the database and add the following code to the Seed() method, all is well and the data looks good directly in the database.

```
 var user = new User
        {
            Email = "",
            Categories = new List<Category>
                {
                    new Category
                    {
                        Description = "Category 1",
                    },
                    new Category
                    {
                        Description = "Category 2",
                    }
                }
        };


context.Users.AddOrUpdate(u => u.Email, user);

   var list = new List()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Description = "Test List",
                UserId = 1,
                Category = user.Categories.FirstOrDefault()
            };

            context.Lists.AddOrUpdate(u =>u.Id, list);
```

Please note that the User owns the categories and you can (should only be able to) create them by accessing the Categories Property.

This gives me;

[image: Categories post-Seed]

[image: Lists post-Seed]

I am using these objects in my controller as such;

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var categories = _usersService.GetUser(User.Id).Categories;
            categories.Insert(0, new Category {Description = "", Id = 0});

            var list = _listsService.GetList(id);

            var viewModel = new EditViewModel
            {
                Id = list.Id,
                Reference = list.Reference,
                Description = list.Description,
                CategoryId = list.Category?.Id ?? 0,
                Categories = new SelectList(categories.AsEnumerable(), "Id", "Description")
            };

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

In the above test, I am using the `List` inserted during the Seed and I can see the `List` does indeed have a `Category`, and the values are correct.

[image]

For information, I am using the following ViewModel. I have been investigation methods to be able to 'select' the `User.Categories` from a DropDown and this appeared to work the best at present.

```
  public class EditViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public Guid Reference { get; set; }
    }
```

The populated ViewModel looks like this;

[image]
and finally, the POST method;

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(EditViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var categories = _usersService.GetUser(User.Id).Categories;

                var list = _listsService.GetList(model.Id);

                list.Description = model.Description;
                list.Category = categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.CategoryId);

                _listsService.Update(list);

                categories.Insert(0, new Category { Description = "", Id = 0 });
                model.Categories = new SelectList(categories.AsEnumerable(), "Id", "Description");

                return View(model);
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

So, in the following scenarios, this is what happens. For clarity, each time I am doing this, I go back to the Lists Index and GET Edit again;

- Select '' from the Dropdown - NO Categories INSERT,UPDATE on Lists table only, setting [Category_Id] = NULL - Correct
- SELECT 'Category 1' from DropDown. INSERT categories, UPDATE lists - NOT Correct

The code being used to update the List is;

```
public void Update(T entity)
{
    if (entity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
    _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now, I know this is something I am doing, but being new to EF, I have no idea.

[image]

Comment: please add complete exception with innerexception.

Comment: Does you _listService have IDisposable inheritance? Possible you miss  this. Other reason can came from Generic implementation.

Comment: There is no exception

Comment: You want edit data but EF insert new?

Comment: It is INSERTing a new Category, where I would simple expect it to to UPDATE the list.

Comment: Doing an insert implies that you've added a new Category (or at least the system thinks you've added a new Category) somewhere down the line.

Comment: Interesting senerio. I would test 2 things: make your pk non generic.. and non virtual. This may not suit your needs but you can rule these out as root cause. Test these these independent of one another.

Comment: @brianchandley Tried your suggestions, same issue, but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was down to how the values were being set.

I needed to set the Foreign Key and assign the value to this.

```
public class List : Entity<int>
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")
    public Category Category { get; set; } 
}
```

and the value was then set as

```
var list = _listsService.GetList(model.Id);
list.Description = model.Description;
list.CategoryId = model.CategoryId;
list.Category = null;
_listsService.Update(list);
```

After this, when getting the list from the repository, both the Category and CategoryID would be populated correctly.

The issue was down the setting the Entity as modified, this internally indicated that the Category was 'new' when in fact it was not. You could also 'attach' and existing category to the entity/context but decided the method above was better.

A slightly better approach to the above would be to create a new 'UpdateList' method which could be called rather than the generic update. This method would perform the setting of the relevant properties outside of the controller method.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but possible you must write your update method as follow:

```
public void Update(T entity)
{
    if (entity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
    var item = _collection.Find(item.Id);

    if (item == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item ));
    _context.Entry(item).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Same issue persists unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be in view, of you don't have the I'd the EF will add new record instead of update the existing record.

Comment: I have the ID of the parent List and use CategoryID to work out the Category.

Answer (score 0):

In general: Watch out for existing classes when you name your custom class (like `List`):

```
public class List : Entity<int>
{
    public Category Category { get; set; } 
}
```

Be shoure that you use the right class in the right namespace.

```
var user = new User
    {
        Email = "",
        Categories = new YourOwnNamespace.List<Category>
            {
                new Category
                {
                    Description = "Category 1",
                },
                new Category
                {
                    Description = "Category 2",
                }
            }
    };
```

**Avoid naming classes and properties to existing names. Beter change `List` class in e.g. 'MyList'.**

Comment: Yes, it is. Absolutely not what the problem is, but thanks.